# Getting server info Discord.NET 1.0

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

So, I just updated to **discord.NET 1.0.1**
I'm trying to make the command 'serverinfo'. It should text back the server name and some other information. In the old version, it was as easy as using-:

```
message.server.Name
```

So I'm a little bit confused. I know servers are now guild.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to get the guild name? Or to send a message?

Answer (score 2):

In the new api, everything is labeled as `Context.` For example, I have a command that lists the number of users in my server. Like so:

```
 [Command("users"), Summary("Gets the amount of users in the server")]
    private async Task GetUsers()
    {
        var count = await Context.Guild.GetUsersAsync();
        var users = count.Count();
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"There are currently {users} users in this server!");
    }
```

You could probably add on to this, just type `Context.Guild.` into your code and you can see a list of everything you can add, like Id, Server name, etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question, however i noticed it has not been answered yet.
This is how to find the SocketGuild using a SocketMessage.

```
Dim Channel As SocketGuildChannel = message.Channel
Dim Guild As SocketGuild = Channel.Guild
```

From this you can get the server name from "Guild" e.g.

```
If message.ToLower() = "server name" Then
    Dim Channel As SocketGuildChannel = message.Channel
    Dim Guild As SocketGuild = Channel.Guild
    message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("The server name is: " & Guild.Name)
End If
```

One thing to note however, this will throw an exception if the message was from a DM. so you might want to put this in a try catch.

Answer (score 0):

In this version of Discord.Net, you have to use context. If you want to get the guild name, you have to use `Context.Guild`. That's all.

```
[Command("serverinfo")]
public async Task Serverinfo()
{
    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"This Discord server's name is {Context.Guild}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SocketGuild server = ((SocketGuildChannel)msg.Channel).Guild;
msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"This server is called {server.Name}, it has {server.Membercount} members and is owned by {server.Owner}")
```

There is more to this, just experiment with IntelliSense a little and you will have all the features right there.

Answer (score 0):

//edit oops its in c# not vb.net
Like that

```
        [Command("guildinfo")]
        [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.Administrator)]

        public async Task guildinfoAsync()
        {
            var embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.WithDescription("Total member : " + Context.Guild.MemberCount + Environment.NewLine + "Guild name : " + Context.Guild.Name + Environment.NewLine + "Guild id : " + Context.Guild.Id + Environment.NewLine + "Owner id : " + Context.Guild.OwnerId + Environment.NewLine + "Owner name : " + Context.Guild.Owner.Username + "#" + Context.Guild.Owner.Discriminator + Environment.NewLine + "total textchannel : " + Context.Guild.TextChannels.Count + Environment.NewLine + "total vocal channel : " + Context.Guild.VoiceChannels.Count);
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed);
        }
```

Result : [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are mutiple things. You can find much things with IntelliSense. Like Server and more.
You can acess them with Context.Guild. or do a variable:

```
SocketGuild server = ((SocketGuildChannel)msg.Channel).Guild;
```